# Forms authenticated on one web server, would like to be authenticated on another too

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

We're using forms authentication (IIS 7 and ASP.Net 3.5) on our domain, `www.ourbusiness.com` and having no problems.  We now wish to add some additional ASP.Net servers that will be on a slightly different domain --`newapp.ourbusiness.com`-- and would like things to be such that someone who has been authenticated on www.ourbusiness.com will be authenticated on newapp.ourbusiness.com.

I've seen scattered reports on how to go about this, but could anyone provide additional guidance?  My understanding for example, is that we would want all servers to use the same machine key so that an authentication cookie on one box is good for all the others, something we're already doing on the `www.ourbusiness.com` domain.  But I'm not sure what else is required or if there are articles explaining the steps involved.  Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle creating the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` and `HttpCookie` yourself. That way you can set the domain for the cookie to handle your subdomains. Like you said your servers need to have the same machine key as well.

```
 FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
        username,
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
        isPersistent,
        userData,
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

      // Encrypt the ticket.
      string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

      // Create the cookie.
      var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket) 
      cookie.Domain = ".ourbusiness.com";
      Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```